# ml64 doesn't produce exe

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, win64

I used this code to assemble hello.asm.

```
ml64 hello.asm /link /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib /entry:Start
```

it produced the obj file but no exe files were produced no errors appeared it just wrote ***Assembling: hello.asm***
according to what I read this command line is supposed to assemble the code and produce exe file

> I was learning x86 assembly and trying to convert to x64
>   I read this intro [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly) from intel and just copied and pasted the code written in the examples section at the end of the article -right before the conclusion-
>   for the ml64.exe file I just used the one in the installation of visual studio, I don't know if this is the right way or not.

here is the assembly code in hello.asm

```
; Sample x64 Assembly Program 
; Chris Lomont 2009 www.lomont.org 
extrn ExitProcess: PROC ; external functions in system libraries 
extrn MessageBoxA: PROC
.data 
caption db '64-bit hello!', 0 
message db 'Hello World!', 0
.code 
Start PROC 
    sub rsp,28h ; shadow space, aligns stack 
    mov rcx, 0 ; hWnd = HWND_DESKTOP 
    lea rdx, message ; LPCSTR lpText 
    lea r8, caption ; LPCSTR lpCaption 
    mov r9d, 0 ; uType = MB_OK 
    call MessageBoxA ; call MessageBox API function 
    mov ecx, eax ; uExitCode = MessageBox(...) 
    call ExitProcess 
    Start ENDP 
End
```

Comment: Try: execute `vcvarsall` first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x4d2c09s.aspx.

Comment: I ran this command *** vcvarsall amd64*** and got this error           
**The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the
configuration might not be installed.**
@rkhb

Comment: I've just installed visual studio 2 days ago from ms official website